# Cannot notarize puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I have an electron app that makes use of the `puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth` library.

However this library has a `chrome.app` inside and I cannot notarize for macOS.

`/var/folders/z3/_825pg0s3jvf0hb_q8kzmg5h0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/MyApp-darwin-x64/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth/evasions/chrome.app: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable`

I have tried to `asar` other stuff in the past but it didn't work, so I have `asar: false`.
Should I use this option for this folder?

I'm not sure when `puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth` introduced this `chrome.app`, but the notarization worked few months ago. Now on new builds I have the error above.

`forge.config.js`

```
const config = {
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: false,
    ...
```

Comment: Well you should code sign this binary first before notarizing

Comment: Unrelated but how did you get it running on electron? I get an error when installing "cannot statically analyze"